# Show table records in view via hook_form

Tags: forms, database

I managed to get things looking a bit better, However I dont know why the checkbox below is showing like the picture. I want to select the checkbox and make it do something with the corresponding article. By the way I have it, will it work? Thanks in advance[image].

`function rss_list_form($form, &$form_state) {

```
$results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {rss_table}");
$i = 0;
foreach($results AS $result) {

    $form[$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#prefix' => '<div style="float:left; margin: 30px;">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form[$result->GUID] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#title' => $result->title,
        '#markup' => $result->description,
        '#prefix' => '<div style="float:clear; background: #e0e2e6; border: 4px solid #c5c9cf; padding: 15px; width: auto; margin-left: 80px;">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $i++;
}
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
);

return $form;
```

}`

Comment: As you are using Drupal 7, and need checkboxes in the table which will be wrapped in Form then you should use [theme_tableselect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_tableselect/7). In this link you will find examples to how to use this theme.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I will post my progress later!

Comment: I am a bit confused, my header would be the Select(checkbox) and Article which includes the 2 table fields in an item. How would I code the $rows[]? is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at the link http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/themeing-drupal-7-forms-tables-checkboxes-or-radios. This will help you in developing this.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get things working like I wanted !! So I will include a screenshot and the code for people on the same boat. [image]

```
function rss_list_form($form, $form_state) {

$header = array(
'article' => t('Article'),
);

$rows = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {rss_table}";
$result = db_query($sql);
    foreach ($result as $dbrow) {
    $rows[$dbrow->GUID] = array(
        'article' =>
        '<h3>'.$dbrow->title .'</h3>'.'<br>'
        .'<p>'.$dbrow->description.'<p>'.'<br>'
        .$dbrow->date .'<br>'.'<em>'.$dbrow->link.'</em>'.'<br>',
    );
    }
$form['rss_select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('No articles found.'),
);
$form['import'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Import'),
    '#weight' => 0,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
);
$form['delete'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Delete'),
);
return $form;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Do it without the table first. Just the form with the form elements. Once you get that right and it works you then have to create a new theme function for it:

- implement hook_theme and define a theme function for the form
- set form['#theme'] in the original form to that of your new theme
  function
- implement the new theme function. Here you need to load all of your
  form elements into structures as required by theme_table, and
  call theme_table on it. And then call drupal_render_children on the
  form so as to render the rest of the form (hidden elements etc that
  are required by Drupal FAPI).

Comment: There is no need of another theme function, since Drupal has one that can be used in this case.